# Kernel syntax in Sklearn for Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to implement Gaussian process regression for 2-D input datasets. I want to modify the Kernel function. The Kernel is defined in the sample code as:

```
kernel = C(1.0, (1e-3, 1e3)) * RBF(10, (1e-2, 1e2))
```

and used to define Gaussian process regressor as:

```
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=15)
```

I know that C is constanceKernel and RBF is radial basis function. I want to know the remaining terms in the syntax defining Kernel.

Comment: There are no further terms and the syntax is plain Python. Are you asking about the meaning of the arguments to the Kernel? You can find out about those in the documentation (e.g. [`RBF`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF), [`ConstantKernel`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.ConstantKernel.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.ConstantKernel)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**C: Constant Kernel** (*Can be used as part of a product-kernel where it scales the magnitude of the other factor (kernel) or as part of a sum-kernel, where it modifies the mean of the Gaussian process.*)

```
ConstantKernel(constant_value=1.0, constant_value_bounds=(1e-05, 100000.0))
```

**RBF: Radial Basis Function kernel or squared-exponential kernel.**

```
RBF(length_scale=1.0, length_scale_bounds=(1e-05, 100000.0))
```

*The RBF kernel is a stationary kernel. It is also known as the “squared exponential” kernel. It is parameterized by a length-scale parameter length_scale>0, which can either be a scalar (isotropic variant of the kernel) or a vector with the same number of dimensions as the inputs X (anisotropic variant of the kernel). The kernel is given by:*

```
k(x_i, x_j) = exp(-1 / 2 d(x_i / length_scale, x_j / length_scale)^2)
```